# How can I Validate All Children of a Form Collection?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, propel

I have spent a long time without making progress on what seems to be a simple problem. I need to allow the user to add up to three references to a form. Each reference will have a name and phone number (two text inputs). I would like to do some simple validation on each one. I have created my `ReferenceType` and nested it into the main form with the following (note, I created the PhoneNumber validator and added the `Null()` just for testing):

```
$builder->add('references', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new ReferenceType(),
    'by_reference' => false,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'label' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array('class' => 'reference'),
    'options' => array(
        'required' => false,
        'label' => false,
    ),
    'cascade_validation' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
      new Null(),
      new PhoneNumber(),
    )
));
```

### ReferenceType:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
    'label' => 'Reference',
    'required' => false,
    'cascade_validation' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Name'
    )
));
$builder->add('phone', 'text', array(
    'label' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Phone Number'
    ),
    'cascade_validation' => true,
    'constraints' => array(
        new Length(array('max' => 14)),
        new PhoneNumber(),
  )
));
```

All of that is quite simple and straight forward. However, I have been unable to get the form to throw an error for any reason related to those references. I use **Propel** for my ORM and have a lot of validation which works correctly on the main form. These references also display and function correctly except for validation. They are all mapped to **one** column (`references`) and I have tried Propel's `type="array"` as well as defining my own getter and setter which serializes the array of items. The `type=array` doesn't work at all with the collection, and serializing it seems to work ok.

I have searched SO and symfony.com docs for an answer but have found nothing that would actually cause either `name` or `phone` to throw an error. I have tried adding validation to my `validation.yml` file without success (3 chars only for testing):

```
references:
    - Valid: ~
    - Collection:
        fields:
            name:
                - Length:
                    max: 3
                    maxMessage: Please limit your reference's name to 3 characters or less.
```

I'm probably missing something very obvious here, but I can't seem to grasp what. I have also dug through the Profiler and everything appears correct in there as well.

Could any provide hints on things to look for? It seems that creating a new database just for references is a little overkill (they don't need to be searchable or anything). [Propel has some information](http://propelorm.org/Propel/cookbook/symfony2/mastering-symfony2-forms-with-propel.html) on collections, but it didn't seem to make a difference. Or am I entirely missing the idea here and perhaps I should implement the fields an entirely different way?

- Symfony 2.6
- [Propel 2](http://propelorm.org/)